# vue dynamic b-table align text-right if column is numeric

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using dynamic b-table. want to align right if the column is numeric else align left . Can you please help me to achieve that ?

Comment: What is `b-table`?

Answer (score 0):

If you can specify which column will hold the numeric values, you can bind the class to the entire column in the fields in your data:

```
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [
        { key: "first", label: "Full Name", class: "left" },
        { key: "last", label: "Last Name", class: "left" },
        { key: "age", label: "Age", class: "right" }
      ],
      items: [
        { first: "John", last: "Doe", age: 42 },
        { first: "Jane", last: "Doe", age: 36 },
        { first: "Rubin", last: "Kincade", age: 73 }
      ]
    };
  }
```

If you cannot determine which column will hold the numeric data, [according to this doc](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#table-colgroup) you can try bind class based on value of cell:

```
    <b-table fixed responsive :items="items" :fields="fields">
      <template #cell()="data">
        <span :class="{ right: typeof data.value == 'number', left: typeof data.value != 'number' }">
          {{ data.value }} </span>
      </template>
    </b-table>
```

But then you need to set display to flex and use justify-content to set the position in the cell (text-align won't work), for example:

```
.right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
}
.left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
}
```

I hope I helped. Have a nice coding.